# How glm::ortho works

Tags: c++, opengl

I am fairly new to OpenGL and I am trying to handle a window resizing event using `glm::ortho`. I am displaying a simple triangle on screen and I am trying to make it so it keeps the same width/height ratio upon window resizing. However, when I resize the window, the triangle just disappears.

Here is my window resizing handling function:

```
int width = 800, height = 800;

void windowResized(GLFWwindow* window, int width2, int height2) {

   width = width2;
   height = height2;

   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
   proj_matrix = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)width, (float)height, 0.0f);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: That is the correct way to set the viewport and projection matrix. I'm thinking the problem may lie elsewhere. How is `proj_matrix` calculated initially?

Comment: It is initialized as follows: `glm::mat4 proj_matrix;`

Comment: How big is the triangle you're rendering? It could be that you're rendering it but it's so small that you don't notice it.

Comment: I don't think so, it's the same size as the original 800x800 window. Here are the vertices coordinates:

`static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
 -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};`

Comment: When you're drawing orthographically, those vertices are sized absolutely. You're drawing an incredibly tiny triangle, most and most of your vertices there are off of the screen. Try these vertices: `{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 800.f, 0.0f, };`

Comment: Thank you! It works, after the first resizing. Originally though, the drawn triangle is huge, because, as I understand, the drawing mode is not the same. So in order for the triangle to always have the same size, should I change the buffer's data upon resizing?

Comment: No. Initialize the `proj_matrix` with `glm::ortho` and the initial size of the window, then the data can stay the same.

Comment: @ColinBasnett You should post your comments as an answer

Comment: What are you doing with `proj_matrix` in your drawing code. `proj_matrix` is not magically jumping into shader uniforms, you've to set it explicitly. BTW: You should always place `glViewport` in the drawing code, never in the display code. Not adhering to this rule makes dealing with FBOs, HUDs drawing and other advanced techniques much harder in the long run.